# AWK If Condition is not behaving as expected

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I am trying a simple String comparison to filter out String values which are equal to "Time"

```
echo Time | awk '{ print $1 ~ !/Time/}'
output --> 0
```

Also,

```
echo 2020-02-01-04:18:17 | awk '{ print $1 ~ !/Time/}'
output --> 1
```

So the above behavior correct as per requirement.

But if the date in echo command exceeding 02-Feb-2020 then sometimes it's behaving incorrectly.

example,
the output of all commands should be 1, but sometimes its returning 0, Could you please point why this is happening.

```
echo 2020-02-03-04:18:17 | awk '{ print $1 ~ !/Time/}'
output --> 1

// This is unexpected
echo 2020-02-02-04:30:09 | awk '{ print $1 ~ !/Time/}'
output --> 0

// This is unexpected
echo 2020-02-02-04:30:09 | awk '{ print $1 ~ !/Time/}'
output --> 0

echo 2020-02-02-04:30:10 | awk '{ print $1 ~ !/Time/}'
output --> 1
```

Comment: you need to use `!~` and not `~ !` ... but I dunno why the examples you've given behave differently for different inputs

Answer (score 3):

```
$1 ~ !/Time/
```

`/Time/` doesn't match `$0`, so it returns `0` (false). So now we have:

```
$1 ~ !0
```

`!0` is `1`. `1` is converted to a string in `~` context. So now we have:

```
$1 ~ "1"
```

and it returns `1` when `$1` has the string `1` and 0 if it doesn't.

```
2020-02-03-04:18:17
              ^  ^  - prints 1

2020-02-02-04:30:09 - no "1", prints 0
2020-02-02-04:30:09 - no "1", prints 0

2020-02-02-04:30:10
                 ^  - has a "1", prints 1
```

Some more funny tests:

```
$ echo 1 | awk '{ print $1 ~ !/Time/}'
1
$ echo 0 | awk '{ print $1 ~ !/Time/}'
0
$ echo 1 Time | awk '{ print $1 ~ !/Time/}'
0
$ echo 0 Time | awk '{ print $1 ~ !/Time/}'
1
```

Comment: Where is my comment?